# jacobi method overwriting old x

Tags: java, scope, numerical-methods

For some reason my Jacobi method is overwriting the x_old variable.

```
public static double[] Jacobi(double[][] A, double[] b, double tol) {
    int m = b.length;
    double[] x = b;
    double err = tol*100;
    while(err > tol) {
        double[] x_old = x;
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            double sum = 0.0;
            for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                if(i != j){
                    sum += A[i][j]*x_old[j];
                }
            }
            System.out.println(sum);
            x[i] = (b[i]-sum)/A[i][i];
        }
        printVector(x);
        printVector(x_old);
        err = norm(subtract(x,x_old));

    }
    return x;
}
```

The test code

```
    double[][] A = {{1.48 , 5.244, 0, -2},{4, 2, 4, 7}, {9, 2, 11, -3}, {-1, 0.2, 3, 12}};
    double[][] B = {{92 , 1.3, 0.5, 0.5},{2, 23.3, 1, 0.3}, {0, -2, 28, 3.3}, {-1, 0.2, 3, 12}};
    double[][] v = {{2 , 1, 1, 0},{4, 3, 3, 1}, {8, 7, 9, 5}, {6, 7, 9, 8}};
    double[] x = {-2, 4, 13.2, 0.22};
    double[] y = {1.5, -3, 8.87, 0.6};

    double[] c = MyMath.Jacobi(B,y,1e-10);
```

results in

0.8349999999999993
9.06445652173913
3.015575667102071
0.516473922373577

[0.007228260869565225 -0.5177878335510356 0.20908658331778313 0.0069605064688685785 ]
[0.007228260869565225 -0.5177878335510356 0.20908658331778313 0.0069605064688685785 ]

clearly the program quits out because the error becomes zero. I don't understand how this works. Any ideas?

Also a side note, I have another function that overwrites A.

```
public static double[][] cholesky(double[][] A) {
    int m = A.length; // rows
    double akk, akjkk;
    for(int k = 0 ; k < m ; k++){
        akk = A[k][k];
        for(int j = k+1 ; j < m ; j++){
            akjkk = A[k][j]/akk;
            for(int i = j ; i < m ; i++){
                A[j][i] -= A[k][i]*akjkk;
            }
        }
        for(int i = k ; i < m ; i++){
            A[k][i] /= Math.sqrt(akk);
        }
    }
    return A;
}
```

I'm sure there's an obvious solution to this, but when I pass say a matrix U into the function, then try to access U later, I receive the overwritten version. Is there a way to change this without making a copy of the matrix in the function?

Comment: You are re-declaring `old_x` each time through the `while` loop. Is that what you intend?

Comment: haha no, i was told to do that in an earlier question i posted. I figured it can't hurt at least in terms of troubleshooting this problem.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone's curious this code works:

```
    public static double[] Jacobi(double[][] A, double[] b, double tol) {
    int m = b.length;
    double[] x_old = new double[m];
    double[] x = new double[m];
    double err = tol*10;
    while(err > tol) {
        System.arraycopy(x,0,x_old,0,m);
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            double sum = 0.0;
            for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                if(i != j){
                    sum += A[i][j]*x_old[j];
                }
            }
            x[i] = (b[i]-sum)/A[i][i];
        }
        err = norm(subtract(x,x_old));
    }
    return x;
}
```

It's probably a memory allocation issue when setting x = x_old. IIRC using the equals sign with java actually references the old variable (which I did twice with b too). Used to Matlab. With the cholesky function, from my understanding I believe the only real solution is calling a new variable inside the scope of the function, I wish this could be avoided for memory issues, but then again, if I want to store the original A and create a new matrix of the same size, I believe that the overall memory consumption would not be altered much. The only question I have is whether or not I can set `double[][] MatrixInsideFunction = A;` or if i have to do a copy array again.